# ScrambleSuit Server configuration

Tags: pluggable-transports, obfsproxy

How does one run (and verify) a scramblesuit server. I'm using the following configuration:

```
 ServerTransportListenAddr scramblesuit 0.0.0.0:65222
 ServerTransportPlugin scramblesuit exec /usr/local/bin/obfsproxy \
        --log-min-severity=debug \
        --log-file=/tmp/scramblesuit-server.log \
        managed
```

As I understand it, this auto-generates a password that I can use with the client. I have the ORPort of 443 (listening on 0.0.0.0) and it's enabled as a bridge. I've found some people connect back to confirm that it's working using a command like

```
obfsproxy scramblesuit --password=XXXXXXXX client my.external.ip:65222
```

When I try to connect manually using the above command, the obfsproxy log does not show anything is connecting. Similarly when I try to connect manually using the TBB Experimental build it does the same thing. I've confirmed I can poke at the service using netcat and it logs that something is trying to connect.

I've installed obfsproxy from pip (not Debian or from source) and is running version 0.2.12.

My question is does someone see a mis-configuration and second, does someone have a good way of verifying whether or not obfsproxy is running correctly by connecting to it via loopback.